# laravel 5.2 nginx 1.10 windows only home page is working

Tags: php, nginx

laravel5.2 , nginx 1.10 windows enviroment. laravel home is working any other route is not working. please help me about this issue. how i can set url rewrite in nginx.conf to getting work correctly.Below is my configurations .

what is missing in this configurations.please check it and provide solution.

```
    code
    server {
        listen       85;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   D:\Nginx1103\html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
try_files $uri =404;
          # root           html;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
           #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME D:\Nginx1103\html\valeroo$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
         location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
         }
    }
```

this is my updated code

```
 server {
    listen       85;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    root D:\Nginx1103\html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            autoindex off;
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
               rewrite /(.*)$ /index.php last;
               break;
            }
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }
    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
          access_log off;
          log_not_found off;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
     location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
     }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
        expires 365d;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Move `root` directive to outside of location.

2) Change location rule to:

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      autoindex off;
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
         rewrite /(.*)$ /index.php last;
         break;
      }
}
```

3) Fix location for .php extention to be:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Overall:

```
root D:\Nginx1103\html;
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        autoindex off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite /(.*)$ /index.php last;
           break;
        }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: @juni updated my answer, check now, taken from real app

Comment: i am also using this link to configure https://github.com/daylerees/laravel-website-configs/blob/master/nginx.conf

Comment: why not just run in cmd: `php artisan serve` ?  why You waste time for playing with configs in environment that will not exist when You'll push it to server? :)  in fact Your latest config is good, I cannot predict what's Your problem.